# Como utilizar o atributo pattern com expressão regular de maneira correta?

Tags: html5, regex

Eu gostaria de utilizar um `pattern` no meu `input` (tem que ser do tipo `text`) com as seguintes regras:

- O input só aceita até 4 caracteres.
- Esses caracteres só podem ser números de 0 à 9.
- O usuário NÃO pode começar digitando 0. Ex:

  - 0100, 0001, 0050 (Não pode)
  - 1020, 1000 (Pode).

Comecei fazendo o seguinte código abaixo, mas não está dando muito certo.

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="cod" name="cod" pattern="[0-9]+$" maxlength="4" placeholder="Digite o código da empresa(Somente números)" required autofocus />
```

Porém não deu muito certo. (Nesse caso do meu código, não consegui nem impedir que o campo receba só números).

**OBS**: Gostaria de utilizar só o `pattern` do input, sem JavaScript ou jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `pattern` igual a `^[1-9][0-9]{0,3}$`:

```css
/* deixar borda vermelha enquanto o campo for inválido */
input:invalid {
  border: red 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^[1-9][0-9]{0,3}$" maxlength="4" placeholder="Digite o código da empresa(Somente números)" required />
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` são respectivamente o início e fim da string. Assim você garante que o campo só terá o que estiver especificado na regex.

Em seguida temos a [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[1-9]`, que corresponde a um dígito de 1 a 9. Isso garante que o primeiro dígito não pode ser zero.

Depois temos `[0-9]{0,3}`: [de zero a três](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) dígitos de 0 a 9.

Ou seja, o campo pode ter de 1 a 4 dígitos, e o primeiro não pode ser zero. Com isso, o campo não aceita valores como 0100 e 0999, mas aceita 1010, 2999, 1, 12, 999 etc. [Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/sV8fh2/3/) alguns exemplos desta regex em funcionamento.

---

Lembrando que o atributo `pattern` não vai impedir que o usuário digite informações inválidas. Ou seja, o usuário pode digitar "abcd", e o `pattern` será usado para verificar se o que foi digitado corresponde à regex (e se estiver, o formulário pode ser submetido).

Comment: Se eu quiser que aceite de 1 à 4 caracteres é só tirar aquele {3} ? Ai aceitaria o número '999' e não aceitaria o '012' ? (No caso, eu gostaria que o usuário pudesse digitar de "1 à 4" números. Não somente "4" caracteres).

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson Atualizei a resposta

Answer (score 1):

**DEFINIÇÃO DE USO**

> O atributo `pattern` especifica uma expressão regular em que o valor do elemento `<input>` é verificado no envio do formulário.

**DICA**

> Use o atributo de título global para descrever o padrão para ajudar o usuário.

**NOTA**

> O atributo padrão funciona com os seguintes tipos de entrada: texto, data, pesquisa, `url`, `tel`, `email` e `password`. Saiba mais sobre expressões regulares no nosso tutorial de JavaScript.

**SINTAXE**

```
<input pattern="regexp">
```

**ONDE** `regexp`

> Especifica uma expressão regular na qual o valor do elemento `<input>` é verificado.

Um exemplo onde, um elemento `<input>` com `type = "password"` que deve conter 6 ou mais caracteres:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
    Password: 
    <input type="password" name="pw" pattern=".{6,}" title="Six or more characters">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**EXPRESSÃO REGULAR PARA O SEU CASO DE USO**

> **1)** `[0-9]{4}` :Onde pega dígitos de 0 a 9 e somente quatro deles
>
> **2)** `^[0]` :Onde pega o dígito zero correspondente do início da linha

Agora eu te deixo [este site](https://pt.infobyip.com/regularexpressioncalculator.php), para você **testar as expressões regulares separadamente e conseguir entender o que está ocorrendo**, te deixo também um **desafio para você conseguir unir os mesmos**, **assim conseguindo a sua regras de negócio do seu caso de uso.**

[FONTE ORIGINAL - W3SCHOOLS](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

Comment: Sim, Thiagão. Eu agradeço a resposta. Porém, isso eu já conheço. O meu problema é criar uma expressão regular que cumpra os requisitos que eu citei na pergunta.

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson a sua pergunta o entendimento dela está levando para o caminho a qual eu dei a resposta, porém irei acrescentar há minha resposta o que você comentou. Aguarde um momento..

Comment: Mas dei uma bela de uma explicada na descrição da pergunta. Acho que ficou bem resumido ali.

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson tudo bem para você está resposta?

Comment: Foi boa sim, Thiago. Mas achei a do hkotsubo mais completa. Mas muito obrigado mesmo assim.

Answer (score -1):

Podes usar uma expressão regular igual a isso no teu formulário html pattern="^[1-9][0-9]{0,3}$" mas atenção isso não impedir que o teu input recebe letras.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).